# WordPress oddity with broken images (part 2)

Tags: php, wordpress

Can you tell me your opinion of this, and possibly see if you can recreate it? There are TWO scenarios:

**SCENARIO 1 (works as intended)...**

The $post->post_content variable contains this (with a VALID image src):

```
(string) "before [hw] <img src="/path/to/valid_image.gif" /> after"
```

This code placed at the top of the theme header.php...

```
1: echo test_out();
2: 
3: function test_out() {
4:     global $post;
5:     error_log( 'stage_1' );
6:     $str = $post->post_content;
7:     error_log( 'stage_2' );
8:     var_dump( isset( $str ) );
9:     error_log( 'stage_3' );
10:    $str = test_core_wp( 'test_shortcode', $str );
11:    error_log( 'stage_4' );
12:
13:    return $str;
14: }
15:
16: function test_shortcode( $content ) {
17:    return str_replace( '[hw]', 'Hello World!', $content );
18: }
19:
20: function test_core_wp( $function, $a = NULL ) {
21:    $wrap = array ( 'test_shortcode' => 'test_shortcode' );
22:
23:    if ( isset( $a ) ) $args[] = $a;
24:
25:    return call_user_func_array( $wrap[ $function ], $args );
26: }
```

Outputs this **(correctly)...**

```
bool(true)
before Hello World! <img src="/path/to/valid_image.gif" /> after
```

With this in the PHP log **(correctly)...**

```
[22-Jul-2009 11:49:36] stage_1
[22-Jul-2009 11:49:36] stage_2
[22-Jul-2009 11:49:36] stage_3
[22-Jul-2009 11:49:36] stage_4
```

**SCENARIO 2 (where the problem occurs)...**

The $post->post_content variable now contains: (with an INVALID image src):

```
(string) "before [hw] <img src="/path/to/broken_image.gif" /> after"
```

Outputs this **(STILL correctly)...**

```
bool(true)
before Hello World! <img src="/path/to/broken_image.gif" /> after
```

With this in the PHP log **(THIS IS THE PROBLEM)...**

```
[22-Jul-2009 11:56:11] stage_1
[22-Jul-2009 11:56:11] stage_2
[22-Jul-2009 11:56:11] stage_3
[22-Jul-2009 11:56:11] stage_4
[22-Jul-2009 11:56:11] stage_1
[22-Jul-2009 11:56:11] stage_2
[22-Jul-2009 11:56:11] stage_3
[22-Jul-2009 11:56:11] PHP Warning:  Missing argument 1 for test_shortcode() in
/path/to/header.php on line 16
[22-Jul-2009 11:56:11] stage_4
```

The `test-out()` function seems to be running itself TWICE, but only when `$post->post_content` contains a broken image.

FYI, with Firefox you can reload the web page source by hitting `CTRL-R`. When reloading the source, no problems. However, when reloading the web page in the browser tab (or ANY browser), I get the warning shown above.

I have confirmed the oddity only occurs when there is a broken img src in the variable $post->post_content (or any of the $post variables, for you WordPress gurus).

Any chance you can reproduce this and tell me what you think? I'm new to PHP, but I'm pretty sure something is going on that is way beyond my knowledge. :)

**EDIT:**

I was about to start checking my local dev environment, but a friend wrote me:

> After looking at your post, I think I
>   may have an idea what's going on.
>
> I had assumed that the warning message
>   you were talking about was being
>   displayed in the browser when you
>   loaded the page in question, but your
>   post indicates that you're seeing the
>   warning message in the PHP log
>   instead.  Is it *only* appearing in
>   the PHP log? **YES**
>
> If that's so, then consider this
>   explanation....
>
> In the case where you the post body
>   contains an  tag to a valid
>   image, then your code is being run
>   once to generate the page as expected.
>   The browser sees the rendered page and
>   then attempts to load the image.  The
>   server finds the image and dishes it
>   up directly - no surprises here.
>
> In the case where the post body
>   contains an  tag to an invalid
>   image, then your code is being run
>   once to generate the page, just as
>   before.  Then the browser makes a
>   separate HTTP connection to attempt to
>   load the image.  Normally, it would
>   just trigger a 404 error and the
>   browser would display a broken image,
>   end of story.  However, if the broken
>   image URL is to something under your
>   Wordpress installation, then Wordpress
>   overrides the default web server 404
>   behavior and dishes up a fancy "404
>   Not Found" page instead of the web
>   server's default 404 page.  Here's the
>   kicker -- Wordpress's fancy 404 page
>   includes the same header and footer as
>   all the other pages it displays.  So
>   if you have this code at the top of
>   your header, it'll get called again by
>   the 404 page that the web server sends
>   in response to the missing image your
>   browser requested from it.
>
> You never actually see the 404 page in
>   this case, because it's being
>   generated in response to an 
>   request, not a page request, so the
>   browser just treats the response as a
>   bad image and shows the broken image
>   icon, but it is actually being
>   generated and sent.
>
> Compare this (a valid image URL under
>   a Wordpress installation):
>
> http://www.example.com/foo.jpg
>
> to this (an invalid image URL under a
>   Wordpress installation):
>
> http://www.example.com/foo.jpg
>
> Note the custom 404 page including
>   header that gets returned...?
>
> And...  in the context of the 404
>   page, the $post object doesn't exist,
>   so $post->post_content obviously isn't
>   a string.
>
> I had assumed that the warning message
>   was being displayed in the browser on
>   the original page load, which is why I
>   didn't really consider this situation,
>   but if it's just being output to your
>   PHP log, then it makes perfect sense.
>
> And if that is the case, then you can
>   either ignore the warning as it really
>   makes no difference, or you can test
>   for that situation in your code (like
>   the isset workaround you mentioned
>   before).
>
> Any other thoughts, let me know, but
>   that seems to fit with what I know
>   about it so far.

Comment: Thanks for this. It was a very fun exercise :-)

Comment: Haha, good stuff, Josh!  And it only took me four days of playing around until someone emailed me the right answer. Right to my inbox. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it *only* appearing in the PHP log?

**Yes.**

OK.  Then the custom 404 handler being run on the request for the missing image is almost certainly what is causing the warning.  Since the warning's not being displayed anywhere, it's safe to ignore, or you can use your isset test if you don't want it cluttering your log.  In any event, it's really a non-issue, but at least now you know where it was coming from and that it's not a sign of some real problem.

I don't think that (DEV) environment should have anything to do with it at all.  It'd behave the same way on a live server with a real DNS entry set up.

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe I didn't think of that -- DUH!!!! Your friend is 100% correct. It's firefox loading the broken image, which wordpress is serving, thus running your code twice.